# Is it acceptable to write "the innovative Picasso"?

Tags: sentence-construction, adjectives, sentence-structure

> By including pieces of cloth, newspaper, wallpaper, and other materials in his work, **the innovative Picasso was an important influence on** twentieth-century art.

How is using "the innovative Picasso" correct here? Can adjectives be added just after the introductory clause ends, i.e. "the innovative" after the comma and before *Picasso* in this sentence.

Comment: I don't have a clear rule for this, though it sounds perfectly acceptable to me. This reminds me of the name *The Great D'Anton* in *The Prestige (2006)*.

Comment: That's a absolutely valid use. Consider: Alexander the Great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What a delightful question! The inquisitive Random Codemonkey has spotted another curious grammatical construct.

Yes, there is precedent for this wording. There's nothing wrong with putting an adjective (or two) right before a noun, and an introductory clause in front of those words won't change this. For example:

> Visible through the early mist, the grand white hotel gleamed in the morning light.

[image]

I wonder if that sentence seems as awkward as the one you found. If not, then perhaps it's the use of an adjective before a person's name that's throwing you off? If so, then be assured – it's perfectly normal. In fact, here's another example of that being done; it's an excerpt from a theater [review](http://www.styleweekly.com/richmond/love-and-art/Content?oid=1645991):

> Mincks is charismatic as **the eccentric Einstein**, and **Bechard's intense Picasso** shows a great artist in the process of self-discovery.

By the way, if you're wondering whether *intense* refers to Picasso's character or yo Bechard's *portrayal* of that character, then congratulations! The sentence is a bit ambiguous in that regard, and either interpretation could be applied. (Perhaps the "right" meaning would be more obvious if I had seen the play.)

Here's another example from a 2012 children's [biography](https://books.google.com/books?id=kX-GAwAAQBAJ):

> Over the years that followed, the United States Patent Office would grant **the innovative Edison** a total of 1,093 patents.

We could easily rewrite that so that the adjective-name combination followed the introductory clause:

> Over the years that followed, **the innovative Edison** earned a total of 1,093 patents from the United States Patent Office.

Comment: A lucid explanation and loved the way you framed the answer.Thanks mate!